# Сборка без spring-boot-maven-plugin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Для чего нужен `spring-boot-maven-plugin`, когда я убираю этот плагин, создается обычный рабочий **war**, который я могу устанавливать и он нормально запускается.
Вот если добавлю обратно создается на 5 мегабайт больше war. У меня два вопроса:
1. Зачем нужен spring-boot-maven-plugin
2. Почему в варнике который собрался без этого плагина, не указан main class в manifest.mf и нормально устанавливается. Как вообще он узнает что запускать
вот что в Manifest.mf

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: sbt-tanikin-e
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_162



<build>
    <finalName>${name}-${version}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Встречный вопрос, а для чего Вы подключаете этот плагин? Или Вы взяли пример с другого проекта? Если Вы создаете обычное WAR приложение без Spring для развертывания в том же Tomcat, то этот плагин Вам не нужен. Если же вы хотите создать исполняемый war или jar, тогда нужен [ссыль на оф доку](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html)

Comment: Да это с интернета скопировал, использую spring boot. Я запускаю этот проект в wildlfy, в будущем планируется в websphere application server. И что значит исполняемый war. Насколько я понимаю исполняемый может быть только jar, а war для деплоя на сервер. По ссылке я не нашел ответа, почему устанавливается без mian-class, а так же что дополнительного дает кроме того что он записывает в Manifest.mf main-class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Зачем нужен spring-boot-maven-plugin

Чтобы jar файл бы запускаемым - т.е. вам не нужен какой-либо контейнер для запуска (он будет внутри jar - томкат по умолчанию), а только java:

```
java -jar target/mymodule-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Он становится запускаемым т.к. в манифест прописывается имя класса с main-методом.

> 2. Почему в варнике который собрался без этого плагина, не указан main class в manifest.mf и нормально устанавливается.

Нет плагина - нет main-class'a :-) Если под "нормальной установкой" вы подразумеваете ручной деплой в контейнер (wildlfy в вашем случае), то для этого не нужен main-class.

> Как вообще он узнает что запускать вот что в Manifest.mf

Берется первый класс, имеющий main-метод. Вы можете указать класс в настройках плагина с помощью опции [mainClass](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.10.RELEASE/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html#mainClass):

> The name of the main class. If not specified the first compiled class found that contains a 'main' method will be used.